# PHP: Not able to add all values to the string

Tags: php

I am trying to add unknown number of parameters to a string in PHP.

Here is code:

```
<?php 
print "Get parameters";
$myFile = "wr.txt";
$fh = fopen ($myFile, 'w') or die ("can't open file");
$stringData = '';
//$st = '';
foreach ($_REQUEST as $k => $v) {
        $date = date ('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $stringData = $k.":".$v."Date:".$date."\n";      
        fwrite ($fh, $stringData);
        fwrite ($fh, $stringData);
        fclose ($fh);
}
?>
```

But it is adding only last parameter value.

I also tried like

```
$stringData += $k.":".$v."Date:".$date."\n";
```

And put this:

```
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

Outside to the for loop but in that case it is writing 00 in the `wr.txt`. Please help me how can i write all the paramets in a line by date.

Thanks

Comment: `+=` is addition, string concatenation you want `.=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `PHP` `.` is used for concatenation `+` is not used for concatenation.

change this

```
$stringData +=$k.":".$v."Date:".$date."\n";
```

to

```
$stringData .= $k.":".$v."Date:".$date."\n";
```

Comment: Oh I am python turned php programmer

Comment: @masterofdestiny So do the changes. :)

Comment: @masterofdestiny: can i have your gmail id please?

Comment: whoa gotta personal ...  email gmail ...:P

Comment: @VinothBabu  rahulpaul183@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks man. Just to add you in gmail chat so we can share our knowledge. :)

Answer (score 0):

Move `close ($fh)` away from the loop:

```
$myFile = "wr.txt";
$fh = fopen ($myFile, 'w') or die ("Can't open file");

$date = date ('Y-m-d H:i:s');
foreach ($_REQUEST as $k => $v)
    fwrite ($fh, "$k: $v Date $date\n") or die ("Cannot write to file");

fclose ($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

use "." instead of "+", in php concatenation operator is "."

Answer (score 0):

SEE THE LINES :

```
$stringData .=$k.":".$v."Date:".$date."\n";//** ADD CONCATENATION '.' BEFORE '='** 
fwrite($fh, $stringData); //PUT THIS OUT SIDE THE LOOP
fwrite($fh, $stringData); //**REMOVE THIS **
fclose($fh); // **PUT HIS OUT SIDE THE FOREACH LOOP**
```

Try this :

```
<?php 

print "Get parameters";
$myFile = "wr.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = '';
//$st = '';
foreach($_REQUEST as $k => $v) {
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $stringData .=$k.":".$v."Date:".$date."\n";//** ADD CONCATENATION '.' BEFORE '='**  
        //fwrite($fh, $stringData); PUT THIS OUT SIDE THE LOOP
        ///fwrite($fh, $stringData); //**REMOVE THIS **
        //fclose($fh); // **PUT HIS OUT SIDE THE FOREACH LOOP**
}
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess what you are trying to do. but try this:

```
<?php 
print "Get parameters";
$myFile = "wr.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = '';
//$st = '';
foreach($_REQUEST as $k => $v) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $stringData = $stringData . $k.":".$v."Date:".$date."\n";
}
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Hope that helps.